# Formik async field validation with yup schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

In my case, I have a yup schema form validation.
For example:

```
const form = yup.object().shape({
firstName: yup.string().nullable().required(),
lastName: yup.string().nullable().required(),
country: yup.string().nullable().required()
    .test('validator', 'country is incorrect', value => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            api.post('url', value)
            .then(() => 
                  resolve(false))
            .catch(() => 
                  resolve(true)
        })
    }
});
```

Also, I want to validate **country** field **asynchronously**.

---

The flow should be the following:

- Synchronous validation should run
- IF no SYNCHRONOUS validation error
- THEN run ASYNCHRONOUS validation
- IF no ASYNCHRONOUS validation form should be valid

Issues that I faced:

I tried using .test() from yup but the order of validators was wrong.

For example, in this case, I want to execute the required validator and only if it's passed successfully without errors then run .test() (async validation).

How to achieve such behavior with Formik and Yup?

Comment: You can try the .when() yup method and make you async call when the country field is not empty

Comment: Hello @MiDas,
How to get country field in .when() method in this case?
example: country: yup.string().when(what should be here, {........

Comment: sorry. Noo need for when. You have the value of the field in your test method, check whether or not it is empty before you make the api call. If it is empty just return true

Answer (score 2):

Yup allows you to customize a method to implement functions through `Yup.addMethod()`

So a wrapper method called `sequence` can be like this:

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.string, 'sequence', function (funcList) {
  return this.test(async (value, context) => {
    try {
      for (const func of funcList) {
        await func().validate(value);
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      return context.createError({ message });
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

Then we can do this:

```
username: Yup.string().sequence([
        () => Yup.string().max(20), // first check 
        () => Yup.string().required('Username is required'),  // second check
      ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this can be achieved:

```
const form = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().nullable().required(),
  lastName: yup.string().nullable().required(),
  country: yup.string().nullable().required()
    .test('validator', 'country is incorrect', value => {
      if (!_.isEmpty(value)) {
        const isDuplicateExists = await checkDuplicate(value);
        console.log("isDuplicateExists = ", isDuplicateExists);
        return !isDuplicateExists;
      }
      // WHEN THE VALUE IS EMPTY RETURN `true` by default
      return true;
    })
});

function checkDuplicate(valueToCheck) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let isDuplicateExists;

    // EXECUTE THE API CALL TO CHECK FOR DUPLICATE VALUE
    api.post('url', valueToCheck)
    .then((valueFromAPIResponse) => {
      isDuplicateExists = valueFromAPIResponse; // boolean: true or false
      resolve(isDuplicateExists);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      isDuplicateExists = false;
      resolve(isDuplicateExists);
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a good solution though in my case things are a bit more complex. I've to use 3 other values to validate the field in question. The field is a numeric and based on other 3 values I need to check if the value of the field is within a certain range (range has already been captured as a global context). Then I also need to check if the value is NOT duplicate by making an API call. As the field is part of a Material Table (material-table\core), I have to ensure that the value is NOT duplicated within the table. So, this is something BEFORE user submits multiple values by posting the form data. Hope I am making sense here.